# IE11 losing session or cookie info after window.open

Tags: session, cookies, internet-explorer-11

Here's my problem

1. I have a website(X1.com) which contains a login and a button(window.open) after login to open another app (X2.com) in a detached window.
2. this X2.com has list of items and when I double click an item it is supposed to open X1.com/item1.

All of this was working as expected when I was using IE9, chrome and firefox.

But when updated my IE9 to IE11 double clicking the item on X2.com is taking to the login page of X1.com saying session timed out. Chrome still works fine. When I close/logout and login again to X1.com keeping X2.com window    open X2.com is able to open that X1.com/item1 page properly.

Is there an internet option or security setting or a plugin in IE that's blocking X2.com from opening X1.com/item1 page first time?

My company uses IE11 only for operations and that's why I have to get it working. Please ask if my question is not clear. I can provide the exact urls if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common issue in IE11, as a workaround add registry entry of value 0 at:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/Internet Explorer/Main/TabProcGrowth

Comment: Prompting customers to "set registry flags" is NOT a good way to handle this. What if a customer is not qualified to do this, either due to lack of knowledge or due to lack of authority on the computer in question?